# How to Move Pages (not copy) from one site to another site within a Site Collection in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, 2019, sitepages, move

I want to Move (Not copy) one page say `test1.aspx` from `Pages library` of Site1 to the `Pages library` of Site2 within same site collection.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, "copy to" is the only available OOTB feature to copy pages from one site to another site in SharePoint 2019. I don't think it is possible to move pages (not copy). And in some blogs they are using CSOM to copy pages.

For Reference:

[Identify The Modern Pages And Copy Them To Another Site Collection](https://medium.com/@softreeconsultings/identify-the-modern-pages-and-copy-them-to-another-site-collection-b794b890709)

[Clone or Copy SharePoint Pages/Sites Pages Library Files, Folders and Webparts from one site to another using CSOM](http://jenkinsblogs.com/2016/07/27/clone-or-copy-sharepoint-pagessites-pages-library-files-folders-and-webparts-from-one-site-to-another-using-csom/)